# Determining the complement space $\overline{M}$ and orthogonal complement $M^{\perp}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The problem i'm trying to solve reads as follows:

Let $E = \{ x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ...) \in l^2 : x_k \neq 0 \: \text{only for finitely many} \: k \}$ equipped with usual $l^2$ inner product. Set $M = \{ x \in E : \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = 0 \}$. Determine $\overline{M}$ and $M^{\perp}$.

How do you tackle a problem like this? I know that in our Hilbert space $H$ and $l^2$ inner product that we should get that $M^\perp$ = $\{x \in H : \langle x,c\rangle = 0, \forall c \in M\}$ but i can't see a way to compute this.

Any suggestions and ideas on how to start on a problem like this are appreciated!

Comment: What does $\overline{M}$ mean? I'm used to it being the closure, but you say it's the complement? Do you mean it is the set complement $E \setminus M$, i.e. the set of points in $E$ that are not in $M$?

Comment: To develop your understanding, have you tried exhibiting particular elements of $M^{\perp}$?  Or (as a stepping stone to that subgoal), specific elements $v$ of $M$ for which you can concretely describe $\{v\}^{\perp}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, you're correct. It should be the closure of $M$, i got confused with the notation in the book.

Comment: @leslietownes I tried somewhat. I though, since $k$ is finite and our sum goes up to infinity, that we could split our sum up into two parts as $\sum_{n=1}^k x_n +\sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} x_n = 0$ but i don't know if this would help in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to describe how to tackle problems like this. I would start with an uneducated guess as to the structure of $\overline{M}$, guessing either that it is equal to $M$ or $E$. If there isn't another "natural" choice, that's usually what the exercise points towards. I would start by trying to prove $M$ is not closed, by searching for counterexamples, and if I succeeded, then I would try proving $M$ is dense (and if that failed, I'd have to think again).

If we wish to show $\overline{M} \neq M$, one thing is for sure: we will have to use the infinite-dimensionality of $E$. We need a sequence $x^n \in M$ such that $x^n \to x \notin M$. The map $x \mapsto \sum x_n$ is a linear map on $E$ (it's always defined, as the sequence is eventually $0$, though it may not be continuous), and so if we just take $x^n$ in a finite-dimensional subspace of $E$, then the map will be continuous, which will guarantee $x \in M$ too. So, we will need our $x^n$s to have unbounded numbers of non-zero terms (e.g. we can't expect $x^n_m = 0$ for all $m > 1000$ and all $n$).

My idea is, let's take sequences that start strongly with a $1$, then spend the rest of the sequence balancing out this $1$, but spreading the balance out over a longer and longer tail. The first term can be
$$x^1 = (1, -1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots).$$
Then the next term can spread the $-1$ over two terms:
$$x^2 = \left(1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, \ldots\right),$$
then three terms,
$$x^3 = \left(1, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, 0, \ldots\right),$$
etc:
$$x^n = \left(1, \underbrace{-\frac{1}{n}, -\frac{1}{n}, \ldots, -\frac{1}{n}}_{n\text{ times}}, 0, 0, \ldots\right).$$
Each sequence belongs to $M$, it should hopefully converge to $x = (1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, and it makes full use of the infinite-dimensionality. We have
$$\|x^n - x\| = (1 - 1)^2 + n\left(0 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + 0 + 0 + \ldots = \frac{1}{n} \to 0.$$
So, indeed, $x^n \to x \notin M$. That is, $M$ is not actually closed!

Is there anything special about $x = (1, 0, 0, \ldots)$? No, not really. You can pick any sequence $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, 0, 0, \ldots)$ that you like, and if the sum of the terms is non-zero, then you can balance the sum as we did before:
$$x^n = \left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, -\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m x_m}{n}, -\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m x_m}{n}, \ldots, -\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m x_m}{n}, 0, 0, \ldots\right).$$
These also belong to $M$, and a similar argument should show that this tends to $x$, making $M$ dense.

As for the orthogonal complement, well, what is the orthogonal complement of a dense subspace?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This cleared up my thoughts on how to work for this problem!